# Does JAX RS has any alternatives for org.json.JSONObject

Tags: json, api, jax-rs, resteasy

I am trying to write a MessageBodyReader using JAX-RS (RestEasy). And then want to convert the mapper to JSONObject, at this moment I am using org.json.JSONObject for that purpose.

Do we have any alternative in JAX-RS itself for JSONObject?

Comment: what do you mean by mapper? ObjectMapper?

Answer (score 1):

JAX-RS doesn't define any specific JSON [de]serialization library.

However among libraries that implement `MessageBodyReader` you should find some that use [jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson). You could use jackson's `ObjectMapper` as the json deserializer for your `MessageBodyReader`.

A naive implementation would look like:

```
MessageBodyReader mr = new MessageBodyReader() {

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Override
    public Object readFrom(
            Class type, Type genericType,
            Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType, MultivaluedMap httpHeaders,
            InputStream entityStream) throws IOException, WebApplicationException
    {
        return mapper.readValue(entityStream, type);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isReadable(Class type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        return true;
    }
};
```